# Package external project files as a resource jar (SBT)

Tags: java, scala, build, sbt, packaging

I've a javascript project and a scala project on GitHub. I want the scala project to checkout the js project and package it as a resource jar for the scala project.

The following code seems not to work.

```
lazy val myJsProj = RootProject(uri(
  // The project will be checkout to ~/.sbt/0.13/staging/089ea13043e2818509b4
  "https://github.com/foo/bar.git")) 

lazy val root = Project(
    id = "my-scala-proj", base = file("."),
    settings = Defaults.coreDefaultSettings
  ).dependsOn(myJsProj)
```

In the scala project directory, there are some files in `src/main/resources`. Now I run the command `sbt clean package`. I noticed only files under `src/main/resources` are packaged in `my-scala-proj_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, but no files of my js project is included.

I also found an empty jar `~/.sbt/0.13/staging/089ea13043e2818509b4/my-js-proj/target/scala-2.10/my-js-proj_2.10-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I guess `dependsOn` does not mean to include all files to the project? Could someone shed a light?

Answer (score 0):

No `dependsOn` is to instruct how one project in your build depends on another project in your repository.

The use of `RootProject` and `uri` is meant to be a convenience for source compatibility, but it's limited in how well works (i.e. `libraryDependencies` works more reliably).

I don't know of a way to include the sources of a javascript project from a remote source (via `uri`). I think the best place to look is the (sbt) plugins for [sbt-web](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-web#available-plugins).